# Extracting batches from image list in Tensorflow

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, training-data

I have a list of images(try to train CNN model with custom images), defined and reshaped by:

```
reader.images = tf.reshape(self.images, [-1, 256, 256, 3])
```

Which prints:

```
reader.Images :
[[[[ 127.  255.  127.]
   [ 140.  255.  114.]
   [ 217.  255.   38.]
  ..., 
  [[ 255.  240.    0.]
   [ 255.  241.    0.]
   [ 249.  246.    6.]
   ..., 
   [ 203.  237.   52.]
   [ 152.  251.  102.]
   [ 143.  253.  111.]]

  [[ 255.  184.    0.]
   [ 248.  192.    7.]
   [ 205.  242.   50.]
   ..., 
   [ 255.  139.    0.]
   [ 255.  171.    0.]
   [ 255.  177.    0.]]

  [[ 255.  178.    0.]
   [ 237.  187.   18.]
   [ 131.  240.  124.]
   ..., 
   [ 255.  123.    0.]
   [ 255.  156.    0.]
   [ 255.  162.    0.]]]]
```

I want to train my model, by extracting one batch per iteration. But when i use:

```
image_batch = tf.train.batch(
        [reader.images], batch_size=batch_size, dynamic_pad=True)
```

with `batch_size =1`

I get the whole image as output(same as printed above for whole list images).
I am new in Tensorflow so any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer:

For what you are asking for, you should add `enqueue_many=True`.

## Long answer:

`tf.train.batch` is usually used to create a batch from single item tensors that would come from for example a queue.

So you would might feed it with an image tensor ([256, 256, 3]) and get a batched tensor out ([batch_size, 256, 256, 3]).

It is not generally used to slice batches out of a list tensor. You'd have to load all of the images into memory if you used it that way, which wouldn't be very scalable.

That is at least the default, `enqueue_many=False`:

> If enqueue_many is False, tensors is assumed to represent a single
>   example. An input tensor with shape [x, y, z] will be output as a
>   tensor with shape [batch_size, x, y, z].

If you really want to load all images into memory you could add `enqueue_many=True` to the `tf.train.batch` call.

> If enqueue_many is True, tensors is assumed to represent a batch of
>   examples, where the first dimension is indexed by example, and all
>   members of tensors should have the same size in the first dimension.
>   If an input tensor has shape [*, x, y, z], the output will have shape
>   [batch_size, x, y, z]. The capacity argument controls the how long the
>   prefetching is allowed to grow the queues.

I would recommend reading https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets for further guidance (now documenting the new recommended way of using datasets instead of the previously recommended queues - you can create the batch directly from the dataset rather than calling tf.train.batch).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If someone can provide a simple program/example for this i would appreciate it.